# App crashes after storage permission is granted only on first-time launch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

When my `app` is launched for the first time and I go to a tab where it asks for the `storage permission`, it crashes. After that, it works just fine. Basically, it should create a folder on the `external storage` with a file I have in the `assets folder` in my project after the `storage permission` is granted. After the first-time crash and reopening, it does not crash and places the directory and file correctly. 
If the folder is already on the `external storage` it doesn't crash on the first time launch. Also, I later realized I can get rid of the crash completely by targeting `SDK version 21` but if I do that I cannot update the app on the `Play Store` since I submitted it already with hopes to fix this crash later on. Here is the logcat during the crash:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
08-27 01:16:58.548 17674-17674/com.thirdeclarity.rcmloader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.thirdeclarity.rcmloader, PID: 17674
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=65661, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.thirdeclarity.rcmloader/com.pavelrekun.rekado.screens.main_activity.MainActivity}: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/RCM Loader/hekate-4.0.bin (No such file or directory)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4269)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/RCM Loader/hekate-4.0.bin (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.utils.MemoryUtils.copyAsset(MemoryUtils.kt:15)
    at com.pavelrekun.rekado.screens.payload_fragment.PayloadsView.initList(PayloadsView.kt:47)
    at com.pavelrekun.rekado.screens.payload_fragment.PayloadsView.onRequestPermissionsResult(PayloadsView.kt:81)
    at com.pavelrekun.rekado.screens.payload_fragment.PayloadsFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(PayloadsFragment.kt:33)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FragmentActivity.java:804)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7429)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7280)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4265)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4313) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1645) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
  08-27 01:16:58.689 17674-17689/com.thirdeclarity.rcmloader I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 22378(1560KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(104KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 2.770ms total 145.331ms
```

I am new to Android development and the code I am working with is from an open source project but I believe this is the relevant code for the tab that crashes:

```
package com.pavelrekun.rekado.screens.payload_fragment

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.widget.Toast
import com.pavelrekun.konae.Konae
import com.pavelrekun.konae.filters.ExtensionFileFilter
import com.pavelrekun.rang.utils.ColorsHelper
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.R
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.base.BaseActivity
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.data.Payload
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.screens.payload_fragment.adapters.PayloadsAdapter
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.eventbus.Events
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.logs.LogHelper
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.payloads.PayloadHelper
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.utils.MemoryUtils
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.utils.PermissionsUtils
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_payloads.*
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException


class PayloadsView(private val activity: BaseActivity, private val fragment: Fragment) : PayloadsContract.View {

    private lateinit var adapter: PayloadsAdapter

    override fun initViews() {
        activity.setTitle(R.string.navigation_payloads)

        prepareList()
        initClickListeners()
        initDesign()
    }

    override fun prepareList() {
        if (!PermissionsUtils.checkPermissionGranted(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            PermissionsUtils.showPermissionDialog(activity, fragment, PermissionsUtils.PERMISSIONS_READ_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            initList()
        }
    }

    override fun initList() {
        MemoryUtils.copyAsset()

        adapter = PayloadsAdapter(PayloadHelper.getAll())

        activity.payloadsList.setHasFixedSize(true)
        activity.payloadsList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        activity.payloadsList.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun initDesign() {
        activity.payloadsAdd.setColorFilter(ColorsHelper.getContrastColor(activity, ColorsHelper.resolveAccentColor(activity)))
    }

    override fun updateList() {
        if (this::adapter.isInitialized) {
            adapter.updateList()
        }
    }

    override fun initClickListeners() {
        activity.payloadsAdd.setOnClickListener { addPayload() }
    }

    override fun addPayload() {
        if (!PermissionsUtils.checkPermissionGranted(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            PermissionsUtils.showPermissionDialog(activity, fragment, PermissionsUtils.PERMISSIONS_WRITE_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            getPayloadFromStorage()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PermissionsUtils.PERMISSIONS_READ_REQUEST_CODE -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                initList()
            }
            PermissionsUtils.PERMISSIONS_WRITE_REQUEST_CODE -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getPayloadFromStorage()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.permission_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getPayloadFromStorage() {
        Konae().with(activity)
                .withChosenListener(object : Konae.Result {
                    override fun onChoosePath(dirFile: File) {
                        onChosenFileListener(dirFile)
                    }
                })
                .withFileFilter(ExtensionFileFilter("bin"))
                .withTitle(activity.getString(R.string.dialog_file_chooser_payload_title))
                .build()
                .show()
    }

    private fun onChosenFileListener(pathFile: File) {
        val payload = Payload(PayloadHelper.getName(pathFile.absolutePath), PayloadHelper.getPath(PayloadHelper.getName(pathFile.absolutePath)))

        if (!payload.name.contains("bin")) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.helper_error_file_payload_wrong), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        try {
            MemoryUtils.toFile(pathFile, (PayloadHelper.FOLDER_PATH + "/" + payload.name))

            EventBus.getDefault().post(Events.UpdatePayloadsListEvent())
            LogHelper.log(LogHelper.INFO, "Added new payload: ${payload.name}")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            LogHelper.log(LogHelper.ERROR, "Failed to add payload: ${payload.name}")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is more code that is most likely relevant:

```
package com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.payloads

import android.os.Environment
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.data.Payload
import io.paperdb.Paper
import java.io.File


object PayloadHelper {

    val FOLDER_PATH = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/RCM Loader/"
    const val BASIC_PAYLOAD_NAME = "hekate-4.0.bin"

    private const val CHOSEN_PAYLOAD = "CHOSEN_PAYLOAD"

    fun init() {
        val folderFile = File(FOLDER_PATH)
        if (!folderFile.exists()) folderFile.mkdirs()
    }

    fun getAll(): MutableList<Payload> {
        val payloads: MutableList<Payload> = ArrayList()

        File(FOLDER_PATH).listFiles().forEach {
            if (it.path.contains("bin")) {
                payloads.add(Payload(getName(it.path), it.path))
            }
        }

        return payloads
    }

    fun clearFolder() {
        File(FOLDER_PATH).listFiles().forEach {
            if (it.name != BASIC_PAYLOAD_NAME) {
                it.delete()
            }
        }
    }

    fun getNames(): MutableList<String> {
        val payloads: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

        for (payload in getAll()) {
            payloads.add(payload.name)
        }

        return payloads
    }

    fun getName(path: String): String {
        return File(path).name
    }

    fun getPath(name: String): String {
        return "$FOLDER_PATH/$name"
    }

    fun find(name: String): Payload? {
        for (payload in getAll()) {
            if (payload.name == name) {
                return payload
            }
        }

        return null
    }

    fun putChosen(payload: Payload) {
        Paper.book().write(CHOSEN_PAYLOAD, payload)
    }

    fun getChosen(): Payload {
        return Paper.book().read(CHOSEN_PAYLOAD)
    }
}
```

-
    package com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.utils

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

import com.pavelrekun.rekado.R

object PermissionsUtils {

    const val PERMISSIONS_READ_REQUEST_CODE = 125
    const val PERMISSIONS_WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 126

    private fun requestPermissions(fragment: Fragment, permissions: Array<String>, code: Int) {
        fragment.requestPermissions(permissions, code)
    }

    fun checkPermissionGranted(activity: Activity, permission: String): Boolean {
        val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission)
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    fun showPermissionDialog(activity: Activity, fragment: Fragment, code: Int) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        builder.setTitle(R.string.permission_storage_dialog_title)
        builder.setMessage(R.string.permission_storage_dialog_description)

        val storagePermissionDialog = builder.create()
        storagePermissionDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, activity.getString(R.string.permission_storage_button)) { _, _ ->
            storagePermissionDialog.dismiss()
            requestPermissions(fragment, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), code)
        }

        storagePermissionDialog.show()
    }
}
```

MemoryUtils:

```
package com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.utils

import com.pavelrekun.rekado.RekadoApplication
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.eventbus.Events
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.payloads.PayloadHelper
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import java.io.*

object MemoryUtils {

    fun copyAsset() {
        val assetManager = RekadoApplication.instance.applicationContext.assets
        val sxPayloadFile = assetManager.open(PayloadHelper.BASIC_PAYLOAD_NAME)

        copyFile(sxPayloadFile, FileOutputStream("${PayloadHelper.FOLDER_PATH}/${PayloadHelper.BASIC_PAYLOAD_NAME}"))

        EventBus.getDefault().post(Events.UpdatePayloadsListEvent())
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun copyFile(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) {
        inputStream.use { input ->
            outputStream.use { output ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
        }
    }

    fun removeFile(path: String) {
        File(path).delete()
    }

    fun toFile(file: File, path: String): File {
        return file.copyTo(File(path), true)
    }
}
```

RekadoApplication

```
package com.pavelrekun.rekado

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Application
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate
import com.pavelrekun.rang.Rang
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.logs.LogHelper
import com.pavelrekun.rekado.services.payloads.PayloadHelper
import io.paperdb.Paper

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class RekadoApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: RekadoApplication
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        instance = this

        Paper.init(this)

        LogHelper.init()
        PayloadHelper.init()

        Rang.defaults().primaryColor().accentColor().nightMode().oledMode()
        Rang.init(this)
    }

}
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone examines the code and tries to figure out why clicking on the Payloads tab in the app crashes (just once after the first time install) right after the Storage permission is requested and granted and the "RCM Loader" folder is not found on storage. The app works fine after the crash and creates the folder with the bundled bin file inside the folder but I'm trying to figure out what's causing the crash in the first place: https://github.com/ThirdEyeClarity/RCM-Loader?files=1

Comment: please share your MemoryUtils code.

Comment: Just added to bottom of post

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the logcat with this line :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/RCM Loader/hekate-4.0.bin (No such file or directory)
```

In the code you show us, I'm wondering myself about the `PayloadHelper.init()` method :

```
fun init() {
    val folderFile = File(FOLDER_PATH)
    if (!folderFile.exists()) folderFile.mkdirs()
}
```

I can't see any call to it anywhere in theses samples. 
Could you show us where the `init()` method is used ?

Comment: It's actually not used very much that I could find within the project. I just added what I believe to be the relevant code to the bottom of the post